# Convert skeleton of binary image to polylines

Tags: python, image-processing, polyline

**My goal (simple example):**

Let's imagine a binary image with a set of 1 pixel wide straight lines. The orientation of these lines (i.e. their angle relative to the x-axis) follows some (narrow) distribution, but there are also outliers. I want to be able to:

- find the outliers and eliminate them from consideration
- determine lines with endpoints close to each other and similar angles and combine them into a longer straight line (i.e. replace them by a line from the far end of the first line to the far end of the second)
- determine the average angle of the lines

Though, in my actual use case the lines are not necessarily straight.

**My approach:**

Approximate the lines with poly-lines, i.e. groups of vertex coordinates along the original lines.
Once those poly-lines are created, the rest is rather straightforward:
Convert the poly-lines into a set of straight lines by splitting them if a vertex is too far from the line between the outermost vertices, removing all but these 2 outer vertices and combining the lines as described above.

**My question:**

How can I create a poly-line structure as described above in Python? Is there maybe a library/package that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I constructed something that seems to work. I would appreciate any thoughts and comments on how to improve it. I am using Python 3.7.

First, a list is created containing trees which represent 8-neighbors-connected regions:

```
from treelib import Tree

def extract_regions(image):
"""
Extracts 8-neighbors-connected regions from a binary image.
:param image: A homogeneous list of lists containing binary values (booleans or 1s and 0s).
:return: A list of trees containing 2D pixel coordinates of connected regions. The x axis 
         is assumed to be left to right, y axis top to bottom.
"""

    regions = []
    y = 0
    for line in image:
        x = 0
        for pixel in line:
            if pixel:  # i.e. pixel is 1
                if not in_trees((x, y), regions):  # i.e. pixel is not labeled
                    # create tree of connected region
                    regions.append(create_region_tree(x, y, image_transpose))
            # keep track of pixel position
            x += 1
        y += 1

return regions

def create_region_tree(center_x, center_y, image):
    tree = Tree()
    tag = 0
    tree.create_node(tag, (center_x, center_y))  # root node
    tracker = [(center_x, center_y)]
    for p in tracker:
        # define the 3x3 neighborhood around the center pixel; I try not wrap around, not sure if that's needed
        from_x = p[0] - 1 if p[0] >= 1 else 0
        to_x = p[0] + 2 if p[0] + 2 <= len(image[0]) else len(image[0])
        from_y = p[1] - 1 if p[1] >= 1 else 0
        to_y = p[1] + 2 if p[1] + 2 <= len(image) else len(image)
        # find pixels in the neighborhood and add them to tree
        b = from_y
        for line in image[from_y:to_y]:
            a = from_x
            for neighbor in line[from_x:to_x]:
                if neighbor:
                    if not (a, b) in tree:
                        tracker.append((a, b))  # keeps track of pixels in region
                        tag += 1
                        tree.create_node(tag, (a, b), parent=p)
                a += 1
            b += 1
    return tree
```

Next, these regions are "split up" into a set of poly-lines (to me this seems like the most sketchy function of the bunch, but maybe it's fine?):

```
import numpy as np

def polylines_from_regions(region_trees):
    polylines = []
    for tree in region_trees:
        line = []
        depths = []
        for leaf in tree.leaves():
            depths.append(tree.depth(leaf))
        deepest_leaf_index = np.argmax(depths)
        c = tree.leaves()[deepest_leaf_index]
        while not c.is_root():
            p = tree.parent(c.identifier)
            line.append(c.identifier)
            tree.remove_node(c.identifier)
            if not p.is_leaf():
                for child in tree.children(p.identifier):
                    polylines += polylines_from_regions([tree.remove_subtree(child.identifier)])
            c = p
        line.append(c.identifier)
        polylines.append(line)

    # remove single vector "lines"
    long_lines = []
    for i in polylines:
        if len(i) > 1:
            long_lines.append(i)

    return long_lines
```

These poly-lines are then "straightened out":

```
def straight_line_segments_from_polylines(poly_line_list, max_distance_from_line_squared=4 ** 2):        

    # turn a polyline into a (set of) straight line(s)
    def straighten(p_line):
        end = len(p_line) - 1
        # get coordinates of first and last vector of the polyline
        x1, y1 = p_line[0]
        x2, y2 = p_line[-1]
        # for distance calculation, see below
        factor_x = y2 - y1
        factor_y = x2 - x1
        term = x2 * y1 - y2 * x1
        denominator = (y2 - y1) ** 2 + (x2 - x1) ** 2

        for i in range(1, end):  # i.e. all vectors except first and last
            x0, y0 = p_line[i]
            # calculate distance between current vector and the line between first and last vector of the polyline
            numerator = abs(factor_x * x0 - factor_y * y0 + term) ** 2
            distance = numerator / denominator

            if distance > max_distance_from_line_squared:  # i.e. current vector is too far away from the straight line
                # split the polyline at current vector, convert the now 2 polylines into sets of straight lines
                return straight_line_segments_from_polylines([p_line[:i], p_line[i:]])
        # return start and end vector of the polyline (a now straight line)
        straight_line = [[p_line[0], p_line[-1]]]
        return straight_line

    straight_lines = []
    for polyline in poly_line_list:
        straight_lines += straighten(polyline)

    return straight_lines
```

Finally, these straight lines are compared to each other and combined if they are close and similar enough (this one takes the longest to complete, so any tips are doubly welcome):

```
def combine_straight_lines(line_list, distance_tolerance_squared=5 ** 2,
                angle_tolerance=2, min_line_length_squared=15 ** 2):

    temp_line_list = line_list.copy()
    new_line_list = []
    # translates indices of the distance list (see below) to the corresponding vectors
    # of the 2 lines (0: starting vector, 1: end vector)
    vector_nr_table = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]

    # all lines before last
    for i, line0 in enumerate(temp_line_list):
        keeping = True
        # all lines_after i, as to not "double reference" (a -> b & b -> a)
        for j in range(i+1, len(temp_line_list)):
            line1 = temp_line_list[j]
            distance = (
                vector_distance_squared(line0[0], line1[0]),
                vector_distance_squared(line0[1], line1[0]),
                vector_distance_squared(line0[0], line1[1]),
                vector_distance_squared(line0[1], line1[1]))
            smallest_distance = min(distance)
            # check if the closest line vectors are close enough
            if smallest_distance <= distance_tolerance_squared:  
                # calculate angle of the lines and compare
                angle0 = get_straight_line_angle(line0)['deg']
                angle1 = get_straight_line_angle(line1)['deg']
                angle_diff = abs(angle1 - angle0)
                if angle_diff <= angle_tolerance:  # i.e. angles are similar
                    # determine the vectors of each line farthest away from each other,
                    # replace j with these vectors
                    max_dist = int(np.argmax(distance))
                    v0, v1 = vector_nr_table[max_dist]
                    temp_line_list[j] = [line0[v0], line1[v1]]
                    # line i has been incorporated into j, can be left out from result
                    keeping = False
                    break
        if keeping:
            line_length = get_straight_line_length_squared(line0)
            # skip if too short
            if line_length >= min_line_length_squared:
                new_line_list.append(line0)
    return new_line_list     


def vector_distance_squared(vec0, vec1):
    np_vec0 = np.array(vec0)
    np_vec1 = np.array(vec1)
    result = np.sum(ce.np.square(np_vec0 - np_vec1))
    return result


def get_straight_line_angle(line):
    numerator = line[1][1] - line[0][1]
    denominator = line[1][0] - line[0][0]
    angle = np.pi / 2 if denominator == 0 else np.arctan(numerator / denominator)
    result = {'rad': angle, 'deg': 180 * angle / np.pi}
    return result


def get_straight_line_length_squared(line):
    a = line[1][0] - line[0][0]
    b = line[1][1] - line[0][1]
    length_squared = a ** 2 + b ** 2
    return length_squared
```

This leaves me with a bunch of straight lines (sets of 2 vectors) of reasonable size to work with.